# How to create an ArrayList from a Intstream

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

so I want to put **Person** into an array list but I need to use streams
I have csv file thath give me infomartions
id;name;sex
and a method to turn these into a **Person** object using there id,

```java
private Person readCSVLines(int id);
```

but I want to create a method giving me an arrays list of all of them I know there is 807 id and there will be no one more

I tried this using toMap but it worked giving me a map but I only want an ArrayList:

```java
public ArrayList<Person> getAllPerson() {
        try (IntStream stream = IntStream.range(1, personmax)) { // personmax is 807 here
            return stream.boxed().collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            i -> i,
                            this::readCSVLines,
                            (i1, i2) -> {
                                throw new IllegalStateException();
                            },
                            ArrayList::new
                    )
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to a `toMap` you need [`mapToObj`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-) with [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) like so :

```
public ArrayList<Person> getAllPerson() {
    return IntStream.range(1, personmax)
            .mapToObj(this::readCSVLines)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```

Or better using `List<Person>` instead of `ArrayList<Person>`

```
public List<Person> getAllPerson() {
    return IntStream.range(1, personmax)
            .mapToObj(this::readCSVLines)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Note that you don't need to put `IntStream.range` in a try catch block. it us useless.

Answer (score 3):

In your case you just have to iterate over all of the rows using `IntStream.range(from, to)` and convert each row number into the object read from csv with the help of `.mapToObj()`. It's redundant to use `boxed()` function in this case.
Finally, what you need is

```
    public List<Person> getAllPerson() {
       return IntStream
            .range(1, personmax) // personmax is 807 here
            .mapToObj(this::readCSVLines)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
       }
    }
```

Also, note that your methods should have interface as return type (`List`) instead of concrete implementation (`ArrayList`)